# indicar a la clase que pertenece

Tags: java

tengo un arraylist de la super clase unidad

```
private ArrayList<unidad> equipo = new ArrayList<>();
```

en esa lista se agregan objetos de sus subclases espadachin, muralla, guerrero.
de manera aleatoria con una función retorno un objeto de esa lista.

```
return equipo.get(random.nextInt(equipo.size()));
```

ahora lo que necesito es determinar a cual de las subclases pertenece ese objeto para poder llamar al método correspondiente de la clase, Pero no se como pasar por referencia al objeto a algún metodo,
ni como determinar y definir su clase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

para determinar a que clase pertenerce puedes usar instanceof, de la siguiente manera:

```
unidad unidad = obtenerObjectoAleatorio();
if(unidad instanceof espadachin){
 // hacer lo que necesites
}else if (unidad instanceof muralla){

}.......
```

Comment: Esta solucion es completamente valida, pero solo como comentario, Esta forma introduce algo llamado Conditional Statement Code Smell, lo que viola 2 de los principios solidos (Responsabilidad Unica y Open and Closed Principle). Y en mi experiencia lo mas molesto es el mantenimiento de este codigo. Excelente solucion @AngelDev.

Comment: Exelente solucion @Angeldev la unica duda que tengo es en la parte  "hacer lo que necesites", como me refiero al objeto para hacer uso de un metodo que esta solo en la clase espadachin por ejemplo. muchas gracias

Comment: Hola @AngieCostilla, como ya indentificaste la clase puedes hacer un casting a la clase que necesites y llamar al metodo de esa clase por ejemplo, ((espadachin)objectoUnidad).metododeespadachin();

Comment: Excelente aporte @J.B. esta soluciòn esta bien como para empezar en la programaciòn orientada a objetos y entender como funciona, pero como mencionas se pueden usar otros conceptos de la POO para solucionarlo de manera profesional. Pero me alegra que hayan agregado otro respuesta usando el Polimorfismo y ademàs me alegra tu comentario para que la persona que realizo la pregunta tenga multiples opciones y se valla adentrando en este mundo.

Answer (score 3):

Tal cual usted define el problema usted no deberia tener que identificar el objeto que esta en la lista. Usando polimorfismo usted puede resolver este asunto.

Ejemplo:

```
public abstract class Unidad {
   ...
   public abstract int Size();
   ...
}


public class Espadachin extend Unidad {
   ...
   private int numeroDeEspadas;

   public int Size() {
     // Esto es un invento mio para demostrar una implementacion differente
     return this.numeroDeEspadas * 2;
    }
   ...
}

public class Muralla extend Unidad {
   ...
   private int ancho;

   public int Size() {
     // Esto es un invento mio para demostrar una implementacion differente
     return this.ancho;
    }
   ...
   ...
}

public class Guerrero extend Unidad {
   ...
   private int altura;

   public int Size() {
     // Esto es un invento mio para demostrar una implementacion differente
     return this.altura;
    }
   ...
}
```

Esta solucion es usando una clase abstract, pero la forma que prefiero hacerlo la mayoria de las veces es con una interface.

```
public interface IUnidad {
       ...
        int Size();
       ...
    }
```

Ahora las clases quedarian asi:

```
 public class Espadachin implements IUnidad {  
  ...
 }

 public class Muralla implements IUnidad { 
  ...
 } 

 public class Guerrero implements IUnidad { 
  ...
 }
```

Ahora cuando lo use:

```
// Clase abstracta
private ArrayList<Unidad> equipo = new ArrayList<Unidad>();


// Interface
private ArrayList<IUnidad> equipo = new ArrayList<IUnidad>();
```

El compilador va a saber cual objeto esta en la lista y va a ejecutar la function correcta.

```
return equipo.get(random.nextInt(equipo.size()));
```

Espero esto le ayude a aclarar su duda.